# Compiler outputs 0 at the end of array

Tags: arrays, file, pascal, freepascal

I'm coding a program which reads all the numbers from a text file. But at the end of the array it outputs also "0", but in fact I don't have any 0 in the array.

In the file I have this: 12 456 56 7
But the compiler outputs this: 12 456 56 7 0

### Here's the code:

```
program p3;
uses crt;


 var i:integer;
     f:text;
     v:array[1..1000000] of integer;


 begin

  clrscr;
  assign(f,'numere.txt');
  reset(f);

  i:=1;

  repeat

    read(f,v[i]);
    write(v[i],' ');
    i:= i+1;
    until eof(f);

  readln
  end.
```

---

Comment: Could it be that you have extraneous characters after the last number? For example, a space AND a newline?

Comment: if eoln you must readln

Comment: Even though atm your file is tiny, you should get into the habit of checking that `i` is within the bounds of your array, otherwise one day it will bite you.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Yes, I checked and I noticed if I press ENTER in notepad after i write the numbers, it makes a new blank line resulting in the 0 at the end, so @linuxfan was correct.

Answer (score 1):

I studied Pascal's Wiki, and I tried experimenting with SeekEOLn, and it worked even if there were blank newlines

Here's the code:

```
program p3;
uses crt;
var f:text;
    a:array[1..99] of integer;
    i,j:integer;

begin
 clrscr;
 assign(f,'numere.txt');
 reset(f);
 i:=0;

  while not eof(f) do begin
    if not seekeoln(f) then begin

    inc(i);
    read(f,a[i]);

    end
    else readln(f);
    end;
    for j:= 1 to i do write(a[j],' ');
    close(f);
    writeln;


  readkey
  end.
```

Thanks for your help!
- While reading the file, the code will check if the cursor is at the end of the line, if not, it'll read the first number, and then the second and so on, until it reaches the end of the line, then it will ignore any blanks, because it'll go to the new line. 
I hope this will help anyone with this problem.

Comment: Your answer does not match closely your question... and besides, take the time to explain your code.

Comment: First of all, I'm a newbie in Free Pascal, but I'll do my best to explain how I managed to make it work.

As I stated before, when I wrote the numbers in the file, I pressed ENTER and it took me to the second line, that resulting in making a blank line, causing 0 to appear.

Why SeekEOLn worked? Well, while reading the file, the code will check if the cursor is at the end of the line, if not, it'll read the first number, and then the second and so on, until it reaches the end of the line, then it will ignore any blanks, because it'll go to the new line.

Comment: You're welcome @Laur! I am not really sure that your solution is perfect, but thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

I had tested the code from your original problem in Free Pascal, using the input from **numere.txt** and it's nothing wrong with it. It does what it is supposed to do. So, I am sure that the problem lies within your text file. An extra line break or an extra forgotten character can do "wonders".

Comment: Surprised you can be so sure, seeing as the OP hasn't mentioned what compiler flags are set.  Anyway, how does what you say answer the OP's q, exactly?

Comment: It's true that he didn't explicitly ask something but, because his program's output is different from what he expected, I think it's safe to assume he was asking why does this happen. In this case, I think I answered his question.

PS: I don't think he altered the complier flags for such a program.